# Is logistic regression better for a linearly separable data?

Tags: machine-learning

Regarding classification...
Suppose that it is found a data to be linearly separable( tested the linear separability using SVM/Clustering/Single perceptron etc..)
Can we go with a simpler model like logistic regression (instead of SVM or any other) as they say simple model is the better model

Please correct me if wrong

Thanks in advance !
Surya

Comment: If possible, you should always go for a simpler model. In this case, linear regression.

Answer (score 1):

Don't confuse the algorithm with the model.  With linearly separable data, each of those algorithms *should* return a simple hyperplane, a sum of linear (first-degree) terms with real coefficients.  Thus, each of the *models* is equally simple.

If you're concerned with the simplest *algorithm*, then you do have a point.

I would stick with straightforward SVM: it provides a closed-form computation to determine the optimum separation, based on the nearest N+1 observations (given N features).

Each of the algorithms has its advantages with respect to run-time, clarity, accuracy, etc.  If your criterion is something other than maximum gap, then linear regression (in its closed form) may be the best choice.